# Python: `and` operator does not return a boolean value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, boolean

In Python, an empty list is considered a Falsey value

Therefore this is how things should work:

```
>>> [] and False
False
```

But in reality, python returns an empty list.

```
>>> [] and False
[]
```

Is this intended or a bug?

Comment: You can alway so `bool(...)` if you *absolutely* need a bool.

Comment: @tadman: And nowadays it isn't even that slow! I had some toy code I wrote awhile back where a function ended in `return bool(somelist)` because the caller only needed to know if the `list` was empty or not, they didn't need the contents. That `bool` call slowed the code by ~30% relative to just `return somelist` (with the caller evaluating its booleanness implicity with `if funccall():`). Nowadays, they've optimized global and built-in lookups and used vectorcall to dramatically reduce the overhead of calling `bool`, but it's still higher overhead than implicit boolean testing.

Comment: 99.99% of the time if you think Python (or any interpreter/compiler) has a bug, it doesn't, especially for basic operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's intended. Both `and` and `or` are [defined to return the last thing *evaluated* (based on short-circuiting)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), not actually `True` or `False`. For `and`, this means it returns the first falsy value, if any, and the last value (regardless of truthiness) if all the others are truthy.

It was especially useful back before the conditional expression was added, as it let you do some almost-equivalent hacks, e.g. before the conditional expression:

```
b if a else c
```

could be written as:

```
a and b or c
```

and, assuming `b` itself was some truthy thing, it would behave equivalently (the conditional expression lacked that limitation and was more clear about intent, which is why it was added). Even today this feature is occasionally useful for replacing all falsy values with some more specifically-typed default, e.g. when `lst` might be passed as `None` or a `list`, you can ensure it's a `list` with:

```
lst = lst or []
```

to cheaply replace `None` (and any other falsy thing) with a new empty `list`.

Answer (score 3):

This is how it is supposed to work. `and` will only return the right hand operand if the left hand operand is truthy. Since `[]` is falsy, `and` returns the left hand operand.

Answer (score 2):

That's a totally expected behaviour. To understand it, you need to know how the Boolean operators (`and`, `or`, `not`) work. From the [Boolean Operations documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#and):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Now let's consider your example: `[] and False`. Here, since `[]` is *falsey*, it's value is returned back by the statement which is `[]`.

Above linked Python documentation explicitly mentions:

> Note: **Neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return to `False` and `True`, but rather return the last evaluated argument.**

However, in case you need the return value as boolean, you can explicitly type-cast the value to `True` or `False` using the [**`bool()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) function.

For example, in your case it will return as False:

```
>>> bool([] and False)
False
```